# Install grub to another offline system root partition while keep everyting on current system

Tags: boot, grub2

How to install grub (ie. grub2) onto another offline system root partition, must keep everyting on current system grub configuration untouched, so the current system and its grub.cfg will be used for default boot as usually as is (because the grub installation needed only to get its data to be ISO archived from which can have a ready ISO to dd copy (burn in another term) onto USB flashdisk which'd immediately work grub-booted and live running) ?

Comment: Your question is hardly understandable.